# Connect to a database using php, xampp

Tags: php, database

I'm not sure where I'm supposed to save my .php file, because I saved it in a custom folder, but I'm pretty sure it's not right since I get this error when I go to **localhost/connect.php**

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11

Comment: You have to save it in the `DOCUMENT ROOT` which per default is `htdocs` and this is in your `xampp` folder an default is: `C:\xampp`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your files for XAMPP, should be saved in `htdocs`.

For example, if your installation is in `C:\xampp\` then `C:\xampp\htdocs`.
It could be accessed by `http://localhost/`.

Create a folder `htdocs\db`, then access like `http://localhost/db/connect.php`

Comment: So if next I want to work with the data from that database, where should I put my files?

Comment: @LorenaSfăt If you're working with PHP, you got to put your file here only. Methods of connecting to databases (MySQL, SQL Server), should be written inside your `connect.php`. For references: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Answer (score 1):

your path name should like

```
localhost/yourfoldername/connect.php
```

here `yourfoldername` is the name of your folder you created inside `htdocs`

Answer (score 1):

Your root folder is xampp/htdocs/  whenever you go to localhost from your browser, it is referencing that root folder... save your files inside htdocs